# SQL Pivot View for Single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Have a table:

```
Nomber    Sce    SceValue
10        A      a1b2c3
20        C      d2v3b4
10        B      42b2c3
10        B      5978c3
20        A      edr432
```

I need to create the following listing using a view where there all possible "Sce" and "SceValue" pairs are shown for each individual "Nomber" (9 pairs maximum):

```
Nomber    Sce1    SceValue1    Sce2    SceValue2  ...    Sce9    SceValue9
10        A       a1b2c3       B       42b2c3            B       5978c3
20        C       d2v3b4       A       edr432
```

I would like to achieve this using a View. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select number,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Sce end) as sce_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then SceValue end) as SceValue_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Sce end) as sce_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then SceValue end) as SceValue_2,
       . . .
       max(case when seqnum = 9 then Sce end) as sce_9,
       max(case when seqnum = 9 then SceValue end) as SceValue_9
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by nomber order by sce) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by nomber;
```

Comment: In your code above is "number" used to represent my "Nomber" in the original data, and is "t" the table name I am referencing?

Comment: @cixelsyd . . . `t` is intended to be your table reference.

Comment: My edits in your original code produce the results I need. Edits were - change "number" to "nomber" after first "select", change "t" to "q" before "group". Although the results the query produces are correct please confirm my edits are what you had in mind for conditional aggregation.